# Thoughts on propsed network plan: port forwarding to servers, static IP addresses and DNS

Tags: networking, dns

I'm setting up 4 servers that each have RESTful APIs that go over HTTPS. Because we're in the early stages of a startup, I'm going to host these in my closet.

I have business-class Comcast service, so I can get a static IP address or a series of them. The IP addresses are $10/ea per month, so I can save about $30 if I get just one. I realize this sounds like I'm being super cheap, but we're pinching pennies until we get some customers.

We will probably use one server as a "tools" server that will allow us to reach the other servers via SSH; the other 3 servers will need to have HTTPS open to the internet on the LAN.

I'm considering getting one static IP address, and then using my router to forward HTTPS traffic to the various servers. The port forwarding would look something like:

```
WAN Port    LAN Port    Server
  22         22         Tools
1443        443         Server 1 (API via SSL)   
2443        443         Server 2 (API via SSL)   
3443        443         Server 3 (API via SSL)
```

I would then set up A NAME records in my DNS that would be:

```
tools.mydomain.com   -> <static IP address>:22
server1.mydomain.com -> <static IP address>:1443
server2.mydomain.com -> <static IP address>:2443
server3.mydomain.com -> <static IP address>:3443
```

Is this a reasonable approach? Will it work?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot direct traffic to a specific TCP port with DNS records. You can only point at an IP-address. The client by default uses tcp port 80 for HTTP and port 443 for HTTPS (unless you explicitly name the port to use in the URL).

Furthermore you cannot have multiple HTTPS-based hosts using the same IP address unless they also use the same SSL certificate. That is because the SSL handshake takes place *before* the client reveals to the server which hostname it was trying to reach, so the server can only give out an SSL certificate based on the IP address (and port) that was connected to.

In this particular instance, if you have four servers that actually have the same domain, you can get a wildcard SSL certificate (i.e. it covers *.mydomain.com) and then you can actually get away with one single public IP address for all four servers. Just point all DNS records to the same IP address and then you have the server give out your wildcard certificate which is valid regardless of which hostname the client is using. After the SSL handshake is thus completed, the server can look at the Host: -header in the client request to determine which server the request was actually intended for, i.e. you have one server acting as the HTTPS-endpoint where all HTTPS-requests are received and then internally forwarding to unencrypted request to the correct server (or handle all servernames virtually by one physical server).

If you are using Apache HTTP server I suggest you read about name-based virtual hosts and proxy forwarding:

- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/name-based.html
- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/vhosts.html
- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/proxy.html